# How to start a ZeroMQ thread in an MFC application?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc, zeromq

(Visual Studio 2017, C++ 17, cppzmq 4.6.0)

I'm new to MFC programming. I simply want to make a ZeroMQ reply server on a thread, that will always be ready to receive user requests and run certain functions, in my MFC program.

```
void zmq_server() {
    zmq::context_t context{ 1 };
    zmq::socket_t socket{ context, zmq::socket_type::rep };
    socket.bind("tcp://*:5555");

    const std::string data{ "Hi" };

    while (1) {
        zmq::message_t request;

        socket.recv(request, zmq::recv_flags::none);
        //std::cout << "Received " << request.to_string() << std::endl;

        socket.send(zmq::buffer(data), zmq::send_flags::none);
    }
}
```

I thought I could run it as a thread if I just put it in where the dialogue is initialized:

```
BOOL CMFCApplication2Dlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    ASSERT((IDM_ABOUTBOX & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX);
    ASSERT(IDM_ABOUTBOX < 0xF000);

    CMenu* pSysMenu = GetSystemMenu(FALSE);
    if (pSysMenu != nullptr)
    {
        BOOL bNameValid;
        CString strAboutMenu;
        bNameValid = strAboutMenu.LoadString(IDS_ABOUTBOX);
        ASSERT(bNameValid);

        if (!strAboutMenu.IsEmpty())
        {
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_SEPARATOR);
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_STRING, IDM_ABOUTBOX, strAboutMenu);
        }
    }
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);          
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        

    // TODO
    // thread t1(zmq_server )             <============== PROGRAM DOESN'T RUN WITH THIS LINE

    return TRUE; 
}
```

But the dialogue doesn't even start and I wonder if it's because it's not the right way to run a ZMQ server on a thread. How can I run it on a thread in an MFC program?

Comment: Why did you not run the code under a debugger? It would have instantly pointed you at the core issue: `std::thread`'s destructor throws an exception, in case it's still holding onto a thread resource.

Comment: Correction, sorry, `std::thread`'s [destructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread) calls `std::terminate()` in case the `std::thread` object is still associated with a thread.

Answer (score 0):

You should make std:: thread a member variable of your dialog class and initialise it in onInit. That way you keep the thread in scope for the duration of your program (and crucially you can stop the thread gracefully when your program exits).

Comment: You cannot gracefully stop a `std::thread`. Safely terminating a thread always amounts to the thread function implementing cancellation support. [std::jthread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread) offers a framework for that. With `std::thread` this is all up to you.